# Ionic licence sdk platform not accepted

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework

**I have few errors when i run in my ionic project : ionic cordova build android.**

ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 25 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses

Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 25 not accepted.

FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 25].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.961 secs
(node:17804) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /home/emery/Bureau/my/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 25].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Answer (score 0):

I also faced problem like this one, In Your SDK folder open "SDK manager", in SDK tools part there is SDK build tools, install your build tools, if it is installed just update it.  Other way of opening SDK manager is open android studio->tools-> android-> SDK manager -> SDK tools-> install build tools.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOg8Z.png)